# Caching and invalidating trees when nodes change

Tags: algorithm, caching, tree, computer-science

Supposing I have lists of UUIDs, such that lists are many-to-many with UUIDs.

Is there a way to create a digest of each list, and then query that list of digests by an individual UUID to determine which digests were created with that UUID in its input list.

The use-case is this: I have tree structures I'd like to cache. I can cache the structure in its entirety, and I can also cache the components of the tree. I'd like to be able to cache entire (materialized) trees, but I need to have a way to invalidate such views when a constituent component changes.

Practically, my cache will be backed by Redis. So I am limited by its types and operations.

I am thinking for each tree I could create a Redis set containing all the IDs reachable from the top of the tree. The name of that set would be the ID of the tree, which would be cached separately. When any tree component changes, I could look for sets containing that component, and thereby finding the tree entries with that component and then invalidating them.

Comment: What do you mean by "digest of each list"? Isn't such a digest a collection of the UUIDs of all the lists instead?

Comment: @Tarc by digest I mean some string that is produced by a hashing function that looks at each UUID in the list and produces a string. I would like to then look at a list of such strings, and given a specific UUID, figure out which digest strings were generated with that UUID in the list.